# Nothing Happens after Javascript For-Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a for loop in Javascript that executes perfectly, but nothing after the end `}` of the `for` loop executes such as the `alert("before");` or the `addListener()` function!

```
function deleteRow(rowNum){
    var tablelinks = document.getElementById("table1").rows.length;
    //deletes that row number called
    document.getElementById("table1").deleteRow(rowNum);
    //reorders the row numbers in the delete links to reflect their new position
    for(var i = 0; i < tablelinks; i++) {   
        document.getElementById("table1").rows[i].cells[8].innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="deleteRow(' + i + ')">Del</a>';
    }

    //these things below do not work
    alert("before");    
    addListener()
    alert("after");             
    sumrows()
}
```

Comment: It will be very helpful for you to learn how to look for javascript errors in the browser error console or the debug console whenever things are not behaving as you think they should.  That will show you exactly what line is causing an error in cases like this.

Comment: why is there the jQuery tag, since it is not used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are reading the row length before deleting the target row

```
function deleteRow(rowNum) {
    document.getElementById("table1").deleteRow(rowNum); //deletes that row number called
    var tablelinks = document.getElementById("table1").rows.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < tablelinks; i++) { //reorders the row numbers in the delete links to reflect their new position
        document.getElementById("table1").rows[i].cells[8].innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="deleteRow(' + i + ')">Del</a>';
    }
    alert("before");
    addListener()
    alert("after");
    sumrows()
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AQ9W8/)

Assume that you have 5 rows and you are deleting 3rd row, then `tablelinks` becomes 5 but in the next line you are deleting row 3, now you have only 4 rows. Now when in the loop `i` becomes 4, the `document.getElementById("table1").rows[i]` statement will return undefined as `rows` has only 4 elements not 5.

---

You can simplify it much further by passing the link reference instead of the row num to the delete method like

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Del</a></td>
```

then

```
function deleteRow(link) {
    document.getElementById("table1").deleteRow(link.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex); //deletes that row number called
    alert("before");
    addListener()
    alert("after");
    sumrows()
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XZ4Zq/)

Comment: The reason for this script was to re-order all the targets of the deletes because after deleting a row or two, I would add a few more rows which may have the same IDs. Say I deleted "row 5" of six, leaving me with 5 rows. the last row (now row 5) would have the id of Row 6 and the delete would say "delete row 6". But later when I added a new row after the deletion, the new row would be the real row 6 with id of row 6 and whose delete also says "delete row 6". So  to not have two rows with links that both say "delete row 6", i reorder the links. **does your script account for that?**

Comment: @user3225456 looks like Arun P Johny answered your question, right? I can confirm that his script accounts for your question here in the comments, since you are only adding `onclick="deleteRow(this)` within your `delete text` or `delete button`. You would need to add this to your new rows, too.